# Laravel 5: When store data to database The server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I m new in Laravel and trying to add data to the database via ajax, but it throws this message: "The server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)" I define two routes for this one is for form page

```
        Route::get('/create/{id}', 'Participant\ParticipantProjectDefinitionController@create')->name('participant.project-definition.create');
```

and other route to save this data like this:

```
// To save Project definition Data
        Route::get('/store-project-definition-data/{id}', 'Participant\ParticipantProjectDefinitionController@store')->name('participant.project-definition.store');
```

And the Ajax code I'm using is this:

```
function storeDefinitionFormData(addUrl, token, baseUrl){
    $('#create_project_definition_data').click(function(e){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
        e.preventDefault();

        var form_fields = [];

        var counter = 0;

        $('.form-group').each(function(){

            var values = {
                'field_name' : $('#field_name_' + counter).val(),
                'field_data' : $('#field_data_' + counter).val(),
            };

            form_fields.push(values);

            counter++;
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: addUrl,
            data: {
                '_token' : token,
                'customer_name' : $('#field_name_0').val(),
                'customer_name' : $('#field_data_0').val(),
                // 'form_fields' : form_fields
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert('done');
                window.location = baseUrl;
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('fail');
                if(data.status == 422){
                    errors = data.responseJSON.errors; // => colllect all errors from the error bag

                    var fieldCounter = 0;

                    $('.help-block').show();

                    $('.validation').empty(); // => clear all validation

                    // display the validations
                    $('.validation').css({
                        'display' : 'block'
                    });

                    // iterate through each errors
                    $.each(errors, function(key, value){

                        if(key.includes('form_fields.')){
                            var field_errors = key.split('.');

                            var field_error = field_errors[2] + "_" + field_errors[1];

                            $('#' + field_error + '_error').append("<i class='zmdi zmdi-alert-circle' style='font-size: 15px;'></i> " + value); // => append the error value in the error message
                        }

                        $('#' + key + '_help').hide();
                        $('#' + key + '_error').append("<i class='zmdi zmdi-alert-circle' style='font-size: 15px;'></i> " + value); // => append the error value in the error message
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Controller code

```
 /**
 * create project Definition Form
 *
 */
public function create(request $request, $id){

    $ProjectDefinitionFields = ProjectDefinitionFields::all();

    $ProjectDefinitionFieldRow = ProjectDefinitionFields::where('project_definition_id','=', $id)->get();

    // dd($ProjectDefinitionFieldRow);

    return view('participants.project_definition.create', ['ProjectDefinitionFieldRow' => $ProjectDefinitionFieldRow]); 

}

public function store(request $request, $id,  User $user, ProjectDefinitionFields $ProjectDefinitionFields){

    $project = ProjectDefinitionFields::find('field_id');

    $count = ProjectDefinitionFields::where('project_definition_id','=', $id)->count();

    $pd_id = ProjectDefinitionFields::where('project_definition_id','=', $id)->get();

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

     $data[]= array (
        'field_name'=>$request->get('field_name_'.$i),
        'field_data'=>$request->get('field_data_'.$i),
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        // 'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
        'project_definition_id' => $pd_id,
        // 'field_id' => $projectDefinitionFields->id,
    );            
    }

    $project_data = ProjectDefinitionData::create($data); 
    if($project_data){
        return response()->json($project_data);
    }

}
```

Model

```
on ProjectDefinition 
   public function formFields(){
        // return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ProjectDefinitionFields');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\ProjectDefinitionFields');
   }
on projectDefinitionFields
  public function projectDefinition(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\ProjectDefinition');
    }
```

This is my create.blade.php

```
<form id="create_project_definition_data_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            @csrf
                            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                                <?php $count = 0; ?>
                             @foreach($ProjectDefinitionFieldRow as $value)

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label for="definition_data_<?php  echo $count; ?>" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2  col-form-label" id="field_name_<?php  echo $count; ?>" name="field_name_<?php  echo $count; ?>[]" value="{{$value->field_name }}">{{$value->field_name }}</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                           {{--  textbox = 1
                                            textarea = 0 --}}
                                            <<?php  if($value->field_type = 1){echo "input";}else{echo "textarea";} ?> class="form-control" name="field_data_<?php  echo $count; ?>[]" placeholder="Enter project definition_data" id="field_data_<?php  echo $count; ?>" aria-describedby="field_data_help"></<?php if($value->field_type = 1){echo "input";}else{echo "textarea";} ?>>
                                            <small id="field_data_help_<?php  echo $count; ?>" class="form-text text-muted help-block">
                                                Optional Field.
                                            </small>
                                            <span id="field_data_error_<?php  echo $count; ?>" class="invalid-feedback validation"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <hr />
                            <?php $count++; ?>
                             @endforeach
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="create_project_definition_data">Create Project Defination Data</button>
                                </div>
                        </form>
```

```
@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/participants/project-definition.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        // on document ready
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";

            var indexPdUrl = "{{ route('participant.projectDefinition') }}";

            var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

             {{-- // var addUrl = "{{ route('participant.project-definition.create') }}";  --}}

            storeDefinitionFormData(token, baseUrl);

            // console.log(addUrl);

        });
    </script>
```

ERROR

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/participant/project-definition/create/2kxMQc4GvAD13LZC733CjWYLWy8ZzhLFsvmOj3oT
Request method:POST
Remote address:127.0.0.1:8000
Status code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Version:HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: is your this route `Route::get('/store-project-definition-data/{id}'.....` is post ? if it try updating to  `Route::post(....`

Comment: @Vipertecpro yes I tried on the POST but it shows error message "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST"

Comment: Are you trying to access GET method ?

Comment: yes i did but not work

Comment: I don't understand it why do you want to call GET method via ajax ? ajax suppose to call POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE methods only. What are you trying to achive by calling GET method via ajax ?

Comment: try passing this `var addUrl = "{{ route('participant.project-definition.store') }}";`

Comment: on ajax i use method POST you can see on js code , and i update addUrl and again error "Missing required parameters for [Route: participant.project-definition.store] [URI: participant/project-definition/store-project-definition-data/{id}]. (View: /var/www/html/acumenfuel/resources/views/participants/project_definition/create.blade.php)"

Comment: That is beacuse you've `{id}` in your post method remove it and try

Comment: I used that bcoz I want to insert some foreign key at the same time so with the help of id I fetch that foreign key @Vipertecpro

Answer (score 0):

```php
Route::match(['GET','POST'],'/store-project-definition-data/{id}', 'Participant\ParticipantProjectDefinitionController@store')->name('participant.project-definition.store');
```

You can try this Route it will resolve 405

Comment: ```Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/participant/project-definition/create/2kxMQc4GvAD13LZC733CjWYLWy8ZzhLFsvmOj3oT
Request method:POST
Remote address:127.0.0.1:8000
Status code:
405
Version:HTTP/1.0

Comment: not solved, I m new on laravel and I stuck on this error last two days

Comment: Use only Post Method

Answer (score 0):

Add method attribute in form

```
method="post"
```

Change your route from

```
 Route::get('/store-project-definition-data/{id}', 'Participant\ParticipantProjectDefinitionController@store')->name('participant.project-definition.store');
```

to

```
 Route::post('/store-project-definition-data/{id}', 'Participant\ParticipantProjectDefinitionController@store')->name('participant.project-definition.store');
```

Comment: I tried then I found error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."  and 405 error is still shows

Comment: give `method='post'` attribute in form

Comment: i alsready tried PUT and Post like this way {{ method_field('PUT') }}

Comment: try once deleting {{ method_field('PUT') }} and setting method 'post' in form

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should post here what's your problem and where's your problem we don't need to see all of your code to solve a basic problem. 
Your form should be this:

```
<form id="create_project_definition_data_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>
                            @csrf
                                <?php $count = 0; ?>
                             @foreach($ProjectDefinitionFieldRow as $value)

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label for="definition_data_<?php  echo $count; ?>" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2  col-form-label" id="field_name_<?php  echo $count; ?>" name="field_name_<?php  echo $count; ?>[]" value="{{$value->field_name }}">{{$value->field_name }}</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                           {{--  textbox = 1
                                            textarea = 0 --}}
                                            <<?php  if($value->field_type = 1){echo "input";}else{echo "textarea";} ?> class="form-control" name="field_data_<?php  echo $count; ?>[]" placeholder="Enter project definition_data" id="field_data_<?php  echo $count; ?>" aria-describedby="field_data_help"></<?php if($value->field_type = 1){echo "input";}else{echo "textarea";} ?>>
                                            <small id="field_data_help_<?php  echo $count; ?>" class="form-text text-muted help-block">
                                                Optional Field.
                                            </small>
                                            <span id="field_data_error_<?php  echo $count; ?>" class="invalid-feedback validation"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <hr />
                            <?php $count++; ?>
                             @endforeach
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="create_project_definition_data">Create Project Defination Data</button>
                                </div>
                        </form>
```

You should use 'post' method when you're creating a something new, this is safer than using 'get' method. so change route method too.

```
        Route::post('/store-project-definition-data/{id}', 'Participant\ParticipantProjectDefinitionController@store')->name('participant.project-definition.store');
```

also, in your 'ParticipantProjectDefinitionController->store()' function has 
`$id,  User $user, ProjectDefinitionFields $ProjectDefinitionFields` parameters but your router not. We can fix it like this:

```
Route::post('/store-project-definition-data/{id}/{user}/{ProjectDefinitionFields}', 'Participant\ParticipantProjectDefinitionController@store')->name('participant.project-definition.store');
```

That means you should pass all of them to your controller.
Soo we can edit your ajax call like this:

```
function storeDefinitionFormData(addUrl, token, baseUrl){
    $('#create_project_definition_data').click(function(e){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
        e.preventDefault();

        var form_fields = [];

        var counter = 0;

        $('.form-group').each(function(){

            var values = {
                'field_name' : $('#field_name_' + counter).val(),
                'field_data' : $('#field_data_' + counter).val(),
            };

            form_fields.push(values);

            counter++;
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: addUrl,
            data: { // $id,  User $user, ProjectDefinitionFields $ProjectDefinitionFields
                '_token' : token,
                'id' : 'your_id_field',
                'user' : '{{ Auth::user() }}', 
                'ProjectDefinitionFields' : 'your_definition_fields' // you need to pass type of 'ProjectDefinitionFields'
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert('done');
                window.location = baseUrl;
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('fail');
                if(data.status == 422){
                    errors = data.responseJSON.errors; // => colllect all errors from the error bag

                    var fieldCounter = 0;

                    $('.help-block').show();

                    $('.validation').empty(); // => clear all validation

                    // display the validations
                    $('.validation').css({
                        'display' : 'block'
                    });

                    // iterate through each errors
                    $.each(errors, function(key, value){

                        if(key.includes('form_fields.')){
                            var field_errors = key.split('.');

                            var field_error = field_errors[2] + "_" + field_errors[1];

                            $('#' + field_error + '_error').append("<i class='zmdi zmdi-alert-circle' style='font-size: 15px;'></i> " + value); // => append the error value in the error message
                        }

                        $('#' + key + '_help').hide();
                        $('#' + key + '_error').append("<i class='zmdi zmdi-alert-circle' style='font-size: 15px;'></i> " + value); // => append the error value in the error message
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

before try it, I'll give you a advice. Read whole documentation and review what others do on github or somewhere else

Comment: The reason I used `$id` as parameter and URL is the form field which I displayed is dynamic so to fetch form I used parameter after this while storing data I used `$id` again because I need to inset foreign key with respective inputs.